# XPATH - Referencing a string from a list on each loop

Tags: python, loops, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Using Selenium and XPATH to click on a number of webpages, I would like to iterate over a list of strings - to click on a different webpage for each iteration of a loop.

The list is:

```
y=['Toowoomba','Ascot']
```

To click on the first webpage the code I have is:

```
for j in y:
    button2 = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="(//span[contains(text(),'Toowoomba')])[2]")
    button2.click()
```

How do I iterate over this loop so the next webpage is for Ascot?

My attempt is:

```
for j in y:
    button2 = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="(//span[contains(text(),j)])[2]")
    button2.click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F-string would be a good application for this.

```
for j in y:
    button2 = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=f"(//span[contains(text(),'{j}')])[2]")
    button2.click()
```

But you don't have to use f-string; any text formatting scheme will work, such as good old string concatenation:

```
    button2 = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="(//span[contains(text(),'" + j + "')])[2]")
```

Comment: Excellent thankyou John - appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
for btn_name in y:
    xpath_of_btn = "(//span[contains(text(),'" + btn_name + "')])[2]"
    button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath_of_btn)
    button.click()
```

This is a better complete code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# your list
y = ['Toowoomba', 'Ascot']

# your loop
for btn_name in y:
    xpath_of_btn = "(//span[contains(text(),'%s')])[2]" % btn_name
    button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath_of_btn)
    # test if the button exists before click on it
    if button:
        button.click()
```